# Property not found angular2 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api that returns me a json , and I cast the response to my class this works fine. But the json doesnt contains some varibales in the class and I expect those variables to be initialed with null if its not being set. But they dont appear at all(they disappear) and i get an exception that they are not there whiles they should be there. Pls an explanation on why this is happening would be very satisfying.

```
export class CustomPurchaseOrderProduct {
  constructor(
    public productId: number,
    public productName: string,
    public warehouseName: string,
    public binLocationCode: string,
    public amountInStock: number,
    public sellingPrice: number,
    public productTaxRate: number,
    public calculatedTax: number,
    public unitPrice: number,
    public discount: number
  ) {}
}

  getCustomProductOrders() {
const url = `${this.localUrl}purchaseOrderProducts`;
return this.http.get(url)
  .map(response => <CustomPurchaseOrderProduct[]>response.json());
```

}

```
  getAllPurchaseOrderProducts() {
this.purchaseOrderService.getCustomProductOrders()
    .subscribe(
      response => this.customPurchaseOrderProducts = response
    );
```

}

```
console.log('This is form Object', this.customPurchaseOrderProducts[index].calculatedTax);
```

JSON Object from array

```
{
"productId": 8,
"productName": "Akomka ",
"warehouseName": null,
"binLocationCode": null,
"amountInStock": 0,
"sellingPrice": 0,
"productTaxRate": 10,
"unitPrice": 0
```

}

So I am expecting my CalculatedTax ,UnitPrice and Discount to be null but they are not there when I console log the object

The calculatedTax and other variables are just not in the object when I console log them.

Comment: Why dont you use the `elvis` operator to build the model.
like `public calculatedTax? : number` This will make the field optional

Comment: If properties aren't there, casting won't change that. Casting is only a hint to the tools to allow them to make assumptions, but it has no effect at runtime.

Comment: @RahulSingh I dont want them to be optional i want to  see them be null if there are not being set

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer pls I dont get you point. Why are they not showing

Comment: @user3701188 as gunter pointed out you cannot change . its is just a skeleton to the data , you have to manually set them if you want such a thing better use a elvis operator. or better have a dummy value set from before

Comment: @user3701188 not sure what to explain. Casting doesn't change the value in any way whatsoever. Casting is only a hint to the tools, that they should assume the value conforms to a specific type.

Comment: But then why do the other variables that are not set left as null then why have they disappeared, isnt it suppose to conform to the Class object when it casts. I dont know if you also understand me. and what are your sugguestiions to bring my json into that object having all my object varibales

Comment: @user3701188 its better to have them have a default value

Comment: I am added the json object to make it clear

Comment: @RahulSingh trust me I tried adding a default null but all to not avail , it just doesnt show up

Comment: @user3701188 then  i guess manually you need to check at the time of setting the model

Comment: @user3701188 what are you trying to accomplish here?
Cause your object is not able to set itself. The object is **async** it can be be show in the HTML, but not outside of the `subscribe(//console.log show object)`. If possible show your html to I'm curious how you get your index there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this:

```
.map(response => <CustomPurchaseOrderProduct[]>response.json());
```

you are just telling compiler that you know the shape of the data and that you are sure it matches your class. If you console log the response you can see that it's a plain POJO and will console log `Object {...}`, so it's really not an instance of your class.

If you truly want it to be an instance of your class and have properties that potentially are not there, you can as mentioned in comments have them as optional properties. And if the property does not exist, then assign the null value. So your shortened class:

```
export class CustomPurchaseOrderProduct {
  private productId: number;
  private productName: string;
  private calculatedTax?: number;

  constructor(
    productId: number,
    productName: string,
    calculatedTax?: number

) {
    this.productId = productId;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.calculatedTax = calculatedTax || null
  }
}
```

So above we are marking `calculatedTax` as optional, and if it's not present in response, we assign `null` to the property. Please notice that you need to mark the optional properties as last in the constructor.

Then in the http-request you need to create the incoming data as an instances of your class, so you would need to do:

```
getCustomProductOrders() {
  const url = `${this.localUrl}purchaseOrderProducts`;
  return this.http.get(url)
   .map(response => <CustomPurchaseOrderProduct[]>response.json()
     .map(data => 
      new CustomPurchaseOrderProduct(data.productId, data.productName, data.calculatedTax)
     )
   )
}
```

Using classes vs Interfaces is an debatable issue, some prefer interfaces, some classes. So you could also use interfaces instead, but that alone will not solve the issue though. Solving this could be done also when you are getting response, iterate the data and check if property exists in object, if not, then assign it with `null`. But above is solution is with using class :)